# field extension that is finitely generated but not finite dimensional

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Give an example of a field extension that is finitely generated but not finite dimensional.

I'am really getting stack to find such an example.

I would appreciate any help or hints with that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Like $\Bbb Q[\tau]$ where $\tau$ is transcendental?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  I think better might be $\Bbb Q(\tau)$, i. e. rational functions in a transcendental; I mean, is $\Bbb Q[\tau]$ a field?

Comment: No it is not since there is no polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $p(\pi)=0$

Comment: In general, for any field $K$, you can take the field of rational fractions $K(x)$.

Comment: I am still having a problem with understanding that your example works .

Comment: What do you think of my answer below?

Comment: Are you, perhaps, thinking of *algebraic* extensions only? In that case, [finitely generated algebraic extension is always finite dimensional](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_Generated_Algebraic_Extension_is_Finite).

Comment: Finitely generated as what? If you mean $E$ is finitely generated as an $F$-vector spaces, well... that's what it means for $E$ to be of finite dimension over $F$. If $E$ and $F$ are fields such that $E$ is finitely generated as an $F$-*algebra*, then Zariski's lemma shows that $E$ is in fact finite dimensional as an $F$-vector space, so I'm not sure what your question is going for.

Comment: Alex Wertheim @ You can find this question in page 240, Thomas W. Hungerford - Algebra

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't really need fancy stuff like transcendental numbers or whatever.

> **Definition:** Let $K\subseteq F$ be a subfield. The field $K(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, where $x_i\in X$ and $|X|=n<\infty$, for some subset $X$ of $F$, is said to be finitely generated.

Let $F_1$ be a field, e.g. $\mathbb Q$.

Let $F_1[t]$ be the polynomial ring of one indeterminate $t$ over $F_1$.

Let $F_1(t)$ be the fraction field of $F_1[t]$, i.e. the set derived from adding all inverses of non-zero polynomial in $F_1[t]$ to $F_1[t]$ itself. (One can check that the fraction field is exactly the generated field here.)

In the definition above, taking $F:=F_1(t,s)$ and $K:=F_1$ and $X:=\{t\}$, we see $F_1(t)$ is finitely generated, where we add one more indeterminate $s$ just because we don't want $F_1(t)=F$.

$F_1(t)$ (as a $K$-module or $K$-vector space) has infinite dimension over $K$ because we cannot find a finite subset of $F_1(t)$, say $E$, such that span$_K(E)=F_1(t)$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $F$ is finitely generated since the set $\mathcal{B}=\{1,\pi\}$ is a basis for $F$ with coefficient in $K$. If $[F:K]=n,$ then that would mean there exists $p(x) \in K[x]$ of degree $n$ such that $p(x)=0$, which is impossible. Hence, $[F:K]>n$ for all positive integer $n,$ i.e, $F$ has no finite dimensional.

Comment: first of all, when you wrote $p(x)=0$, did you mean $p(\pi)=0$?

Comment: second of all, did you mean $\{1,\pi\}$ is a basis for $F$ as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space?  because aren't $\dfrac1\pi$ and $\pi^2$ in $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ but not the span of $\{1,\pi\}$?

Comment: The first comment I got it, the second one it is true, but how can I fix that?

Comment: As @J.W.Tanner mentioned, $\{1,\pi\}$ is not a basis for $F$ over $K$.

Comment: Check out my post above.